# html input field not clickable

Tags: html, css, textbox

For some reason my login textbox is not clickable in the main area, only on the bottom-border. I looked at other topics on this issue and people have been advised to check for transparent overlapping elements, I checked and I don't see any - also tried messing with a higher z-index but that also did not work. Would love some input!

```
.input_large {
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-khtml-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px solid #929292;
padding:5px;
width:259px;
background-color:#f6f6f6;
```

}

this is the CSS. The problem is also viewable here: [click](http://clients.amyranth.com/)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I was having a similar issue and just reading your question alluding to transparent overlapping elements / z-index put me on track to solve my problem. What fixed it for me was just increasing the z-index. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `span#status` is overlapping the `input`.  If you reduce the height of the `span` it allows the `input` to be clicked.

```
#status {
    border-radius: 11px;
    height: 50px; /*Height reduced*/
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -100px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

You could also not position this element absolutely, which will allow the `input` to be clicked.  I'm not sure the reasoning behind this element being `position:absolute`.

Comment: Ah, I see what is happening here. I am editing someone else's code; and I put most of their stuff in the Bootstrap framework - I now see that one of the bootstrap classes is messing with the original CSS. The script was written in 2008 I think, so there are some outdated classes in there that I still have to update. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The `<span id=status>` element is in the way.  It is not visible (`opacity: 0`) and blocks the Username control.  Instead of using `opacity: 0`, you can use `visibility: hidden`, but it seems like you could just tweak the height and positioning of the element so that it fills up the white space above the inputs instead.